# Can I keep a counter for Java Threads in the run method?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class variable, sum. Every time I start a new thread, I want the sum to increment. It seems that run is only being called once, and I can't find better info to tell me more about it. Is there a way I could accomplish this with locks? Here is some simple code:

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable{
    static int sum = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
            Thread t = new Thread(new MyClass());
            t.start();
            t = null;
        }
    }
    @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
        ++sum;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Each Object of `MyClass` has its own value for `sum`. You should start by making `sum` static. Then you have to take care of synchronization / thread safety

Comment: I made sum static, and then I synchronized run. It now prints numbers 1 to 5, pauses, then print 1 for 5 lines, having erased the previous 1 to 5...

Answer (score 2):

Keeping mutable state in static variables is a bad practice, but this is how you would fix this to work:

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable {

    static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new MyClass());
            t.start();
            t = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int sum = counter.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not exactly, what OP wants. Addition is thread-safe, printing is not.

Comment: OP says "Every time I start a new thread, I want the sum to increment.", so this is exactly what he wants.  Printing appears to be an incidental part of his debugging efforts.

Comment: oh... ignore my comment, oversaw the `sum` =)

Answer (score 0):

Since sum is instance variable, for instance of `MyClass` there is a variable `sum` with initial value as `0`. Mark the `Sum` as static to use it at class level.

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable{
    static int sum = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new MyClass());
            t.start();
            t = null;
        }
    }

    public void run() {
      synchronized (this) {
        sum++;
       System.out.println(sum);
   }
 }
}
```

This is the output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is still not working. It is erasing 1 to 5, then printing 1 1 1 1 1. Also, why did you comment out t = null? Wouldn't that cause memory leaks in the long run?

Comment: Please make sure you have marked the sum as static. It is working for me.

Comment: @ACHYUTHAPAILI this code is not threadsafe at all. Your answer is simply not working.

Comment: I think I fixed it:                                                                                           `public class MyClass implements Runnable{
static int sum = 0;
`public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {`
   ` for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){`
       ` Thread t = new Thread(new MyClass());`
      `  t.start();`
     `   t = null;`
   ` } System.exit(0);`
`}`
`@Override`
`public void run() {`
       ` sum++;`
   ` System.out.println(sum);`
`}`
`}' //SORRY FOR THE MESSY LOOK, CTRL K doesn't work in comments, I don't know how you're doing it...

Comment: @Goku still not thread-safe. `i++` and `++i` are no atomic operators and are therefore not thread-safe. You need either some kind of lock (implicit via `synchronized` or explicit) or special Types like `AtomicInteger`.